# How to test-run my own app on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

This is not an app that is ready to go out nor is it something that is even in a beta.

As you guys know, there are some things that the simulator cannot ..well.. simulate .

The accelerometer for example has to be on iPhone. Is there a way for me to just upload it on my iPhone and test it? Is there such a thing. I apologize if this has been discussed, I googled for about half hour, couldn't find a thing.

It's something I'm looking to do over and over again just to see how my app is running.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys for answers. I am registered already, but the links you provided have done the job, Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mush join the paid apple developer program.
[See here for instructions and next steps](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/100-Configuring_Your_Development_Assets/identities_and_devices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH4-SW9) -

Answer (score 1):

You can test it with device. But before that, you must get the developer certificate. With that, you can generate a developer provisioning profile. With all these things done, you can install the app to the device and you can test.

For more info, visit the [Apple developer site](http://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/index.html)